# panel background image only shows EVT_SET_CURSOR

Tags: animation, events, bitmap, background, wxpython

I have been working fruitless in animation with wxpython. 
Is it just that wxpython is not suitable for animation ?

I created a frame and then a panel in the frame. 
The panel is for the animation canvas. 
I draw the animation to the staticBitmap attribute of that panel.
Then on the panel, there are several buttons. 
The canvas need frequent changes.

I have two issues here that I would appreciate any help. 
First, the canvas panel is supposed to intercept EVT_LEFT_DOWN and EVT_LEFT_UP.
But the event handlers are never called. 
I checked the event watcher of wxpython widget inspector.
It seems that every time I move the mouse, the only events are EVT_SET_CURSOR.
No EVT_LEFT_DOWN and EVT_LEFT_UP.

The following is my code to bind the events.

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.canvas.canvasClickDown, id = self.GetId())
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.canvas.canvasClickUp, id = self.GetId())
self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.canvas.canvasClickUp)
self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.canvas.canvasClickUp)
self.canvas.staticBitmap.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.canvas.canvasClickUp)
self.canvas.staticBitmap.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.canvas.canvasClickUp)
```

I guess that I am in panic now since I tried to bind the events to the staticbitmap, the panel, and the frame all together. 
But only I saw EVT_SET_CURSOR.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the following 11-year-old page which basically solves my problem.

http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Can-t-get-mouse-events-over-a-StaticBitmap-image-td2339006.html

I guess EVT_SET_CURSOR is kind of basic to all other events and indispensible.

Answer (score 0):

Still the flickering problem is serious. 
I changed to PyGame.